# How to fix this query, php?

Tags: php

An error occurs and no display "Notice: Undefined index: name in..."

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM addhistory");
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
$row1=mysqli_fetch_all($query);

foreach ($row1 as $row)
{
  $sql1=("SELECT name FROM pregister WHERE id='".$row['name']."' ");
  $write1 =mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
 //print_r($sql); exit;
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_array($write1);
//print_r($row1); exit;
   //echo "$description"; exit();
?>
```

Comment: What's the content of addhistory table? Does it include "name" column?

Comment: Does the data fetched from database content name column?

Comment: `$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($write1);` you're overwritting the variable `$row1` which is used already from the main query.

Comment: it contains id, name, date, and description

Comment: Pretty sure this can be written in one query, not two. Read here about it https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery hard to say without seeing table data. This is confusing, looks like you are fetching just name twice.

Comment: @ikiK a join can be enough I think, but hard to tell without seeing the structures of the tables, some input sample along with desired one

Comment: @Cid or join yes, correct.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `fetch_array` returns an array, not an associative array. user `fetch_assoc` to get an aassociative array.

if you want to `mysqli_fetch_all()` get to use associative arrays, also provide `MYSQLI_ASSOC`